# Does git change unmodified and uncommited files in merge?

Tags: git, git-merge

Is it possible that when taking `git pull`, a file that has not been modified locally and has not been committed locally, changes in automatic merge and that the changes, possibly breaking a file, are then committed and pushed as made by me?

The file changes locally of course if a newer version is on the remote.

But shouldn't that file be identical to the one on the remote after pull, unless i've made local modifications? There aren't any branches involved in these transactions.

I believe i just saw this happend, but don't understand how is it possible. What are the conditions that cause unmodified and uncommitted file to be modified with respect to the remote (origin/master) by merge?

Comment: Hard to say without looking at your repository but `git blame` should help identify any commit(s) where local changes were made, if any. Worth double-checking

Comment: This is not expected behavior. I agree with mzulch. Need to trace down the root cause using git blame. Can you share the differences that you found?

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I will look around with git blame and see if i can find/show something.

Comment: I'm starting to believe that i with my collagues have simply misinterpreted (git diff) output on bitbucket. There are three commits involved. First one, say A, from my collague, pushed to remote. At the same time i made the second commit, B, after which i merged remote with pull and made the third commit, C, with simply the result of merge.

If we look at the diff between B and C, we can falsely interpret the changes merged from remote as commited by me! But if we look at the diff between A and C, we find no changes on the file in question.

Comment: When looking the details of a single commit on Bitbucket, it shows the file under "Files changed", which seems to be the cause of our mistake.

When i run
git diff A B <file>
where A and B are the commit identifiers, as in git log, the output is empty. Also
git log file
does not show either B or C.

Doesn't this clearly show that the file was not modified in either of my commits B and C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible that when taking git pull, a file that has not been modified locally and has not been committed locally, changes in automatic merge

Git pull is an alias for 2 commands: `git fetch && git merge` so there might be a merge when you pull code from server. **But** you mentioned that you did not modify the code so there shouldn't be any conflict since no local changes needs to be applied to this file.

If the file has been changed during merge of course you can commit, push and break your build, but still the question remained - Who modified the file and changed it.

---

#### How to track file changes

#### `git bisect`

check when was the file changed

#### `git blame`

Check who changed the given line (last updated for the given line)

#### `git log`

`git log -p <path/to/file/file>` will show you all the log entries for the given file.

---

#### `git diff`

Notice that `git-diff` may show a file changed in a merge commit, even when the file was not changed locally by the local commit being merged. You should look at the diff between the merge commit and the commit on the remote being merged with your local commit to see if the file on remote was actually changed in these transactions.

Comment: Thanks for the edits and the answer! git log <file> helped me figure this out. It was a misunderstanding caused by Bitbucket's misleading output. Your answer will help anyone with the same problem. If you add that git-diff may show a file changed in merge commit, even when the file is not changed locally, i'd be happy to accept your answer.

Comment: What do you want me to add? added what you asked me to

Comment: Basically the whole issue was caused by false interpretation of git-diff. I would just like to wrap this up nice and clean so that anyone stumbling here in the future would find most use of the answers. I'm not sure how to achieve this, so i was suggesting that you would add a note that git-diff will show the file changed in merge, but one must be careful to notice that those changes are caused by merge and exist only in the diff of the local commit and the remote commit being merged. The commit after merge and the remote commit before the local commit show no diff.

Comment: Fell free to edit the answer and add any information that might be helpful. i voted for this question, you should see it soon.

You can edit the answer by clicking on the edit at the bottom of the answer

Comment: You can also add thi sinfor in your question as well.

Comment: I did my best to describe the git-diff behaviour in merge.